# How to create/use a Calendar inside an Android Application (not as an Intent)

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api, custom-component

I am working on an Android application which requires a google synced calendar as part of it. I cannot use an Intent to show up the Android Calendar Activity. It has to be a part of the application. The calendar takes up only half of the screen, and rest of the area should be filled with the application content.

1. Can someone tell me how to go about this?
2. I would have to create a new custom calendar as a View? Or its not possible at all?
3. Is there any custom calendar view available already so that I can plug it and use?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone tell me how to go about this?

Use the Google Calendar GData API.

> I would have to create a new custom calendar as a View? Or its not possible at all?

There is no Calendar widget in Android. You would have to create one yourself or find a third-party widget for this.

> Is there any custom calendar view available already so that I can plug it and use?

None that I am aware of, though you may find one via a search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following articles. The first covers reading a calendar, the second covers creating events:

http://jimblackler.net/blog/?p=151

http://android.arnodenhond.com/tutorials/calendar